# How to move the overflow (that shows the options menu) button in tablet top action bar to the bottom bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to move the overflow button (that shows up the options menu) actually present in the top action bar to the bottom action bar. As actually done by Facebook application and many other applications. I want this for tablet only.

Screenshot:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: "As actually done by Facebook application and many other applications" -- you are welcome to post screenshots providing evidence of your claims.

Comment: Here is an example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CSnrR.png

Comment: The icon should be as shown in: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kQB7G.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, neither of those screenshots show a "bottom action bar". They show the navigation bar.

Second, whatever is shown in your second screenshot is non-standard.

My guess is that second screenshot is supposed to be the legacy menu affordance. The objective of a modern Android app developer is to *not show the legacy menu affordance*, as it is an indication to users that your app is not being maintained. Modern Android apps have the overflow menu in the action bar (for devices without a dedicated MENU button).

That being said, if you wish to have fewer users, and therefore want to suggest to those users that your app is unmaintained, to have the legacy menu affordance, get rid of your action bar, such as by setting `android:targetSdkVersion` to 11 or lower.

You can read more about this in [the documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).